# Cause of PiFace Output LED Noise

Tags: piface

So I've got some code that looks like this:

```
import pifacedigitalio as p
import time

p.init()
while True:
    p.digital_write(0, 1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    p.digital_write(1, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

As the input changes, the indicator LED switches on and off. As it does, it makes an audible clicking sound. Doesn't seem right to me! What could be causing this?

Comment: When you say indicator led, is it pi's internal led's or external led's that you have connected for the project? Thanks

Comment: Output pins 0 and 1 :) Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PiFace includes a relay (2 actually) the clicking sound you hear is the relay (the small black boxes) activating and deactivating. Inside the relay is a small metal arm that moves to make electrical contact. The clicking is normal. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt-4jJvYvzI) explains how a relay works.

Comment: You don't really want to switch mecahnical relays too often.  They have a limited number of cycles.  5 times a second might not be too bad.

Comment: *Yeah - My car has a relay without any contacts (a solenoid?) just to make a tick-tick noise when I use the indicators (turn-signals) as the flasher unit is electronic and totally silent and the Car manufacture thought that a sound was needed for those.*